# Partial Quicksort

Tags: c++, vector, quicksort, partial

My assignment is to make a partial quicksort to rearrange a vector so that the smallest k items appear first, but the rest of the vector remains unsorted. He wants us to base it off of quicksort. I've tried a couple of different things.

Here's my partition function:

```
template <class Comparable>
int partition(vector<Comparable> &a, int first, int last, int &pivotIndex) {
// place the pivot in a[first]
choosePivot(a, first, last);
Comparable pivot = a[first];
int lastS1 = first;
int firstUnknown = first + 1;

for (; firstUnknown <= last; ++firstUnknown) {
    if (a[firstUnknown] < pivot) {
        ++lastS1;
        objectSwap(a[firstUnknown], a[lastS1]);
    }
    // else item from unknown belongs in S2
}
// decide a new pivot
objectSwap(a[first], a[lastS1]);
pivotIndex = lastS1;

return pivotIndex;
```

}

And here's a couple different attempts at partial sort:

```
template <class Comparable>
void partialsort(vector<Comparable> &items, int k) {
int left = 0;
int right = items.size() - 1;
int pivotIndex;

    while (right > left) {
        int newPivot = partition(items, left, right, pivotIndex);

        if (k < newPivot) {
            right = newPivot - 1;
        }
        else {
            left = newPivot + 1;
        }
    }
```

}

```
 template <class Comparable>
 void partialsort(vector<Comparable> &items, int k, int first, int last) {

int pivotIndex;

if (first < last) {

    partition(items, first, last, pivotIndex);

    partialsort(items, k, first, pivotIndex - 1);

    if (pivotIndex < k - 1) {

        partialsort(items, k, pivotIndex + 1, last);

    }
}
```

}

```
void partialsort(vector<Comparable> &items, int k, int first, int last)    {
    int pivotIndex;

if (k < pivotIndex) {
    partition(items, first, last, pivotIndex);
    partialsort(items, k, first, pivotIndex - 1);
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: suppose you have a pivot point, what does that tell you about the elements before and after it?

Comment: the elements before the pivot should be smaller than the pivot, and the elements after the pivot should be larger than the pivot. thats my understanding of it

Comment: And the number of elements to the left of the pivit might be (k-1), or it might be smaller, or it might be bigger.  In any case you only need to handle at most one side of the pivot.

Comment: You may need to keep the original vector, and start over once you determine the correct pivot to get exactly k sorted items.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting#Specialised_sorting_algorithms